# How to get sizeof of array in following case:

Tags: c

I have written a code in C as below,

```
#define SOB1 10
#define SOB2 20

char Buffer_1[SOB1];
char Buffer_2[SOB2];


char * CommandArray[2] = {Buffer_1,Buffer_2};
```

How do I get size of `Buffer_1` and `Buffer_2` indirectly through `CommandArray`?
 More precisely I should know value of SOB1 or SOB2 based on the index of `char * CommandArray[2]`

Comment: Once an array has decayed to a pointer, you loose all array meta-data like the size. All you have left is the pointer it has decayed to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without storing the information yourself, you can't.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do a `sizeof` in this case, since the array metadata has been lost when you started accessing it via pointer.  You would need to use `sizeof(Buffer_1)` or `sizeof(Buffer_2)`.

Another option (if you don't have access to `Buffer_1` and `Buffer_2`) would be to store a second size variable that is equal to the `#define` for each Buffer, and use that.  Since the array doesn't contain a string, you also can't check for `\0` or similar, so you need to be very careful for buffer overruns when using them (another reason to store a size variable).

Answer (score -2):

You can just assign it to the pointer. You need to allocate memory using calloc or malloc.

Comment: char *CommandArray[2]; CommandArray=(char *)malloc(sizeof(SOB1*SOB2));